# Swift on Linux missing a method

Tags: swift, xctest, xctestexpectation

I ran some tests on Swift for Linux today, using the `swift:5.8-amazonlinux2` Docker container.

I was surprised to find that the `fulfillment(of:timeout:enforceOrder:) async` method for asynchronously waiting on test expectations, and which resolves & works as expected on Mac & Xcode, seems to be missing from `XCTest` on Linux.

As far as I can tell, the rest of `XCTest` on Linux seems to be present & work as expected.  (That method is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/4109476-fulfillment#), and has been around since Xcode 11 so it's not a new feature by any means.)

So what am I missing?  Is this method actually not included in Linux, or is there some other way to import it on Linux that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have not yet been added; here is an issue on the open-source version of XCTest noting the absence of `fulfillment(of:timeout:enforceOrder:) async`:
https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest/issues/436